# Can I reference a click event on a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The assignment is to create a click event that will cause the headers to slide up, I am trying to accomplish this task with only one click event reference however this will only work on the first header. Is there a was to accomplish this with out multiple click events?

```
<h1 id="h1">Heading-1</h1>
<h2 id="h2">Heading-2</h2>
<h3 id="h3">Heading-3</h3>

<div id = "result"></div>

<script src="jquery.js"></script>


<script>

    var i= 1;
    $("h" + i).bind('click', function () {
        var thisID = '#h' + i;
        $(thisID).slideUp("slow");
        i++; 
    });
```

Comment: because the selector only runs once, it does not magically update when i is updated. Just bind the click event to each element. You have a reference to it with this or the event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use class instead of ID. Something like

```
<h1 id="h1" class="sliderHeading">Heading-1</h1>
<h2 id="h2" class="sliderHeading">Heading-2</h2>
<h3 id="h3" class="sliderHeading">Heading-3</h3>
```

If you need only header that was clicked on to slide up:

```
   $(".sliderHeading").bind('click', function () {
        var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
        $(thisID).slideUp("slow");
    });
```

If you need all headers to slideup on one click:

```
 $(".sliderHeading").bind('click', function () {
        $(".sliderHeading").slideUp("slow");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I had not really grasped classes yet. Seeing it work to solve this problem really helped me understand the concept better. That fixed my issue and now I am onto my next task!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a class to all of them and use that in your script.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, that was the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it inside the loop, if the number of headers (id) is known.

`for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {`

```
$("h" + i).bind('click', function () {
    var thisID = '#h' + i;
    $(thisID).slideUp("slow");

});
```

`}`